# Is this proof of the derivative of $\ln(x)$ correct?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I just started with calculus at school. For myself I tried to proof why $\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ because I can't "just accept that it's true".

I came up with the following:

$$\ln(x) = y  \Leftrightarrow e^y = x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^y = \frac{dy}{dx}x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^y = 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$

Would this be correct? Somehow I feel uncomfortable just moving $e^y$ to the other side "leaving $\frac{dy}{dx}$ behind" and was wondering if this is actually legal or if there are mistakes or improvements here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning.  In the second line, are you multiplying by the function $\frac {dy}{dx}$ or are you computing the derivative $\frac d{dx}$ of both sides?

Comment: @lulu I guess I meant every $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to actually be $\frac{d}{dx}$.Tried to take the derivative on both sides

Comment: Ok. In that case, use the chain rule to write $\frac d{dx}e^y=\left( \frac {dy}{dx}\right)e^y$ and then proceed just as you have done.

Comment: The derivative of $x$ with respect to $x$ is $1$. So, you can directly jump to line 3 avoiding line 2.

Comment: Worth remarking:  many mathematicians find it clearer to define $\ln x$ by the integral $\ln x = \int_1^x\frac {dt}t$ in which case the claim is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(x) = y  \Leftrightarrow e^y = x$$
$$\frac{d(e^y)}{dx}\ = \frac{d(x)}{dx}$$
$$e^y\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^{ln(x)}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

The notation is not appropriate.

The line of thought that you followed could be written this way.

From $y=\ln(x)$ you can write $e^{y(x)}=x$. Then take derivatives $$1=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial(e^y)}{\partial x}=e^y\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$ where we have used the chain rule in the last equality, the given formula in the second, and the derivative of the identity function in the first.

Therefore $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{e^y}=\frac{1}{x}$.

---

The actual validity of the proof might depend, though, on the definition of $\ln(x)$ that you are given and the result that are allowed to be assumed known.
Is the chain rule know to be true? Are $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ known to be inverses?